# When should you put on your robes?

Tags: zen, traditions, meditation-practicalities

My question is going to be almost to "profane" for this area of SE, about it is a serious concern of mine.

I have just started out zen meditation. One of the suggestions that was given me was that to wear robes while meditating. No problem. But when should I put them on? Should I already wear them on the way to meditation practice (that is, put them on at home, and then take the bus, etc. with them on) or should I start wearing them at the temple?

I apologize again for the type of answer, and thank your for your time.

Comment: You mean like these? http://www.zabuzabu.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm curious as to who told you wearing robes was beneficial.  There are specific ways of wearing robes (as outlined in the vinaya) that can aid in mindfulness, but the simple act of having them on isn't beneficial on its own.  Be that as it may, I wouldn't put them on until you reached the meditation hall.  Wearing them in public has a bit of a "look at me" quality to it.  Taking the more humble approach is almost always best.  (Cue the folks who are going to say that I'm calling monks immodest or saying they shouldn't wear robes! - there is a distinct difference between lay practitioners and monastics on this subject.)

Comment: The main reason due to its being beneficial I suppose is the feeling of inclusion in the sangha, as everybody wears robes. However, it was the owner of the temple, he who leads the practices who told me. Thank you for the answer, by the way, I am of the same opinion.